# Excel VBA: Run-time error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error when trying to add Hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I am new using excel VBA and I am trying to add Hyperlink. Not sure about the error since I found a lot of scenarios with the same error code but nothing related to my own scenario. I am trying to load pdf files from a path folder using 2 command bottoms one to load the files the other one to clean the search. And when I debug the error it is pointing to this specific line:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
```

Below is the entire code, any help will be appreciated it

```vb
Sub LoadFiles()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim Path As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Path = Range("A2")

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path)

i = Range("B1")

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(objFile.Name, Range("A4:A" & Range("B1")), 0)) Then

    Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select

    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path, _
                               TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name

    i = i + 1

End If

Next objFile

End Sub


Sub Clean()

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
    Range("A5").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect ("password"), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't add a hyperlink if the sheet is protected

Comment: Hi Tim, 

Thank you for your response. 

When I removed the lines:

ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")

ActiveSheet.Protect ("password"), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True

I got error  1004: Delete method of range class failed

Comment: After making the change, now I am getting the same error with line 

ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name

Comment: The issue may be connected to the value in cell `B1`: it has to be `>=4`. What is the formula in it?

Comment: You mean on lines:

i = Range("B1")

and 

If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(objFile.Name, Range("A4:A" & Range("B1")), 0)) Then

Should I change B1 for >=4?

Comment: No sure if it is an issue trying to retrieve the path value but now I am getting error for this line 

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path)

Like there is nothing on objFolder

Comment: It's not that simple. What are the values in `A3` and/or `A4`? A title maybe e.g. `PDF files`? And still, what is the formula in `B1`? Note also that `Range(Cells(i + 1, 1), Cells(i + 1, 1)).Select` is the same as `Cells(i + 1, 1).Select` and you don't need to select it. Delete it and just use `Cells(i + 1, 1)` instead of `Selection` as the `Anchor`.

Comment: Rage('B1) is 4 and for Range("A4:A" & Range("B1")) is "File List". On excel I am using A1 to just write down Path on A2 I added the path of the folder where the PDF files are 

Then on A4 I write down "File List". I have to bottoms:"LoadFiles" this is the one giviming issues, the other bottom is just for cleaning the previous search.

Comment: After the changes I a getting error with line Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Path) but my variable Pah shows the file path but for objFolder it seems it is = nothing no sure why if I added as Dim objFolder As Object

Answer (score 0):

### Create List of Hyperlinks

- If you calculate the last row, you don't need the value in `B1`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub LoadFiles()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim FolderPath As String
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    FolderPath = Range("A2")
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    i = LastRow
    
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If Not objFolder Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
        For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
            If Not IsNumeric(Application.Match(objFile.Name, _
                    Range("A4:A" & LastRow), 0)) Then
                ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add _
                    Anchor:=Cells(i + 1, 1), _
                    Address:=objFile.Path, _
                    TextToDisplay:=objFile.Name
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next objFile
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("password"), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder '" & FolderPath & "' not found."
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub Clean()
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If LastRow > 4 Then
        ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("password")
        Range("A5", "A" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete
        Range("A2").Select
        ActiveSheet.Protect ("password"), DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you the code works perfectly. Really appreciate your help